# Slide out menu exit sign moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm using a slide out menu for my website [teamnews.org](http://teamnews.org). The slider is working fine however the cross/x to exit the slider isn't working how I want it to. When click on my menu the cross appears top left hand corner correctly but if I scroll down on my page the cross moves with the page which I don't want it to do. I thought maybe making its position fixed would help but it hasn't. Just wondering how I can stop my cross from moving and just staying where it is when I scroll down. You can the problem on [teamnews.org](http://teamnews.org) just bring click the menu then scroll down. Here is my code for the menu signs

```
.menu-trigger {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px; 
    left: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-trigger span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 30%; 
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    background-color: #303030;
    font-size: 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.menu-open .menu-trigger span {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*Code for three bar burger menu sign*/

.menu-trigger span:before,
.menu-trigger span:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: #303030;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.menu-trigger span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-330%);
    transform: translateY(-330%);
}
.menu-trigger span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(330%);
    transform: translateY(330%);
}

/* styles for clicking burge make it cross */

.menu-open .menu-trigger span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
}

.menu-open .menu-trigger span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
    background:white;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` worked for me here. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.menu-open {
    position:fixed;
}
```